# is it right to make tabulator-js table accessible with custom formatters returning html fragments?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, tabulator

I have to make a static (data is not editable) Tabulator js table accessible. Making it accessible means that

1. sorting can be initiated via keystrokes (no mouse)
2. rows must be selected / deselected via keystrokes (no mouse)

I accomplished these with custom formatters; for sorting I made the header title a "button", for selection I prepended a dummy button in a dummy first column:

```
var tabledata = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Oli Bob', age: '12', col: 'red', dob: '' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May2', age: '12', col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May3', age: '14', col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May4', age: '15', col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982' },
];

var table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  height: 205, 
  data: tabledata,
  layout: 'fitColumns',
  selectable: true,
  columns: [
    //Define Table Columns
    {
      title: '',
      headerSort: false,
      formatter: (cell) => {
        return `<button>select / deselect row</button>`;
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      width: 150,
      headerFilter: 'input',
      titleFormatter: (title) => {
        return (
          `<button>` +
          title.getValue() +
          `</button>`
        );
      },
    },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age', hozAlign: 'left', formatter: 'progress' },
    { title: 'Favourite Color', field: 'col' },
    {
      title: 'Date Of Birth',
      field: 'dob',
      sorter: 'date',
      hozAlign: 'center',
    },
  ],
});
```

But I am not sure if this is correct. Particularly, is it safe to return html in custom formatters? And anyway is there no easier way to achieve my goals?

Full demo is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-61tx3q?file=index.html

Update: there is a built-in "rowSelection" formatter which makes the rows navigable and selectable via keyboard (tab, space) easily. So for the keyboard selection one just needs to add this:

```
columns: [
  //Define Table Columns
  /*
  {
    title: '',
    headerSort: false,
    formatter: (cell) => {
      return `<button>select / deselect row</button>`;
    },
  },
  */
  {
    formatter: 'rowSelection',
    headerSort: false,
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** things to consider here.

First is keyboard operation of the various header controls. Here you need to make sure that you can 'tab' to any of the operable parts.

This is almost working, but I was unable to reach the sort order triangle buttons in the column cells by tabbing, and yes indeed, those elements are not focusable toggles (use either `<button>` -or- `role="button"` with `tabindex="0"`).

The 'tab order' should make sense, and (preferably) should somehow match the visual layout of those controls.

ALL operable controls, including the little sort arrows and the text input field need an accessible name. The name does **not** have to be visible. You can use `aria-label` for a visually-hidden name. This will be announced by assistive tech when the element gets focus.

Take a look at the example at https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/table/sortable-table.html for a viable implementation.

The other thing is to make sure that assistive tech can 'read' the semantics and structure. This is a matter of using the correct semantic HTML and/or ARIA roles. There are constraints about how these roles may be used, and your example is misusing the ARIA roles pertaining to table/grid a little:

The rowgroup role should contain only (semantic) rows, but the tabulator header contains another rowgroup. (This nested one does indeed contain rows). I wonder what is the purpose of the nesting here.

3rd Party accessibility checkers such as ARC toolkit and aXe DevTools will give you plenty more information. Even the far simpler Lighthouse (built into the dev tools of chromium browsers) will offer some useful hints. Good luck!